# SQL Server AutoIncrement Indexes by 1000

Tags: sql-server

This is my first question in StackOverFlow.

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 and the installed SQL Express 2014 (12.0.5000) suddenly all Auto-increment of a database increase from 1000 in 1000 instead of 1 on 1've gone over everything and apparently it's all right. In this database I create a new table and incremental do work well (1 in 1) but the rest not.

Lot of thanks por your help

Comment: Can you share the part of your table create script that defines `IDENTITY`? - most likely you accidentally altered the increment there.

Comment: I have Executed this store procedure EXEC sp_help 'table name'; 
 
 
dentity               Seed     Increment          Not For Replication
IDPresupuesto  1            1                                        0
 
select @@version
 
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2) (KB3171021) - 12.0.5000.0 (X64)
              Jun 17 2016 19:14:09
              Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
              Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Answer (score 2):

Are you referring to identity columns? This query will show you which tables do not have an increment_value of 1.

```
SELECT
    OBJECT_NAME(ic.[object_id]) AS TableName,
    TYPE_NAME(ic.system_type_id) As ColumnDataType,
    OBJECT_NAME(ic.[column_id]) AS ColumnName,
    ic.seed_value,
    ic.increment_value,
    ic.last_value
FROM
    sys.identity_columns ic
WHERE
    ic.increment_value != 1;
```

Comment: I have executed this sql consult and the result was zero number of rows

Answer (score 0):

Go to properties of table (rigth click -> Design), select your column and change identity from 1000 to 1
[image]

Comment: Thanks por your answer but my column´s configuration is exactly the same that you show me in this capture

Comment: I confirm that the configuration for the incrementation is 1 for my table in SQL Server 2016, SSMS 17.6 but it increments by 1000 regardless of this configuration.